# Visio: change format of multiple selected shapes

Tags: vba, visio

I'm trying to create a macro I can call with a right-click to change shape line weight and line color. The shapes are custom shapes that I've created in stencil. I was able to do it successfully to a single shape with this code but it doesn't work when multiple shapes are selected:

```
 Sub Macro1()
 
 Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape

 Set vsoShape = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeID.Item(1)
    
 vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))"
 vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "2.25 pt"

 End Sub
```

I tried iterating through the selected shapes, but haven't found a working way to do it. This was my most recent attempt.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim shapeID As Long
Dim vsoShape As Visio.Shape
Dim vsoSel As Visio.Selection
Dim intCounter As Integer

Set vsoSel = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection

Call vsoSel.GetIDs(shapeIDs)

For intCounter = LBound(shapeIDs) To UBound(shapeIDs)

    shapeID = shapeIDs(intCounter)

    Set vsoShape = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection.shapeID.Item(1)

    vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))"

    vsoShape.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "2.25 pt"

    ActiveWindow.Select vsoSel

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done on your code so far, however there's a couple of issues with your example:

- `shapeID` isn't a property of `Selection`
- `Item` takes an index (in a collection) rather than an ID (use `ItemFromID` for that)
- You need to declare the array: `Dim shapeIDs() As Long`
- To set the window selection at the end you need to use the `Window.Selection` property

Having said all of that the `Selection` object is a collection that you can for-each over directly.

For example:

```vb
    Public Sub Iterate1()
    
    Dim vShp As Visio.Shape
    Dim vSel As Visio.Selection
    
    Set vSel = Visio.ActiveWindow.Selection
    
    For Each vShp In vSel
        vShp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineColor).FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))"
        vShp.CellsSRC(visSectionObject, visRowLine, visLineWeight).FormulaU = "2.25 pt"
    Next
    
    End Sub
```

And as alternative to the SRC syntax you can also use cell name syntax which is often easier to read:

```vb
    vShp.CellsU("LineColor").FormulaU = "THEMEGUARD(RGB(255,0,0))"
    vShp.CellsU("LineWeight").FormulaU = "2.25 pt"
```